# C# Performance of Linq.Any() vs Linq.Where(..).count()>0

Tags: sql-server, linq, c#-4.0, nhibernate, performance-testing

I am hitting an application slowness during a load test for NHibernate LINQ query in .NET application when using LINQ ANY().

Column FileContent is VARCHAR(max).

```
        bool hasIllustrations = CensusIllustration.Linq()
                        .Any(c => c.Participant.Census.Id == census.Id && c.FileContent != null);
```

Above query started taking around 1 min from code while SSMS executes in 1 sec. I took the generated SQL and is as below

```
DECLARE @p0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p0 = NULL;

select top 1 censusillu0_.CensusIllustration_Id as CensusIl1_5_, 
censusillu0_.FileName as FileName5_, censusillu0_.ParticipantId as Particip3_5_, 
censusillu0_.FileContent as FileCont4_5_, 
censusillu0_.CensusParticipant_Id as CensusPa5_5_ from CensusIllustration censusillu0_, 
CensusParticipant censuspart1_ where censusillu0_.CensusParticipant_Id=censuspart1_.CensusParticipant_Id and censuspart1_.Census_id=@p0 and (censusillu0_.FileContent is not null)
```

If I replace the code as below, it executes in 1 sec also from code

```
        bool hasIllustrations2 = CensusIllustration.Linq().Where(c => c.Participant.Census.Id == census.Id && c.FileContent != null).Count() > 0;
```

Generated SQL for this is

--Type and value data was not available for the following variables. Their values have been set to defaults.

```
DECLARE @p0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p0 = NULL;

select cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_ from CensusIllustration censusillu0_, 
CensusParticipant censuspart1_ where 
censusillu0_.CensusParticipant_Id=censuspart1_.CensusParticipant_Id and 
censuspart1_.Census_id=@p0 and (censusillu0_.FileContent is not null)
```

I tried spending time studying the slowness of ANY() on big data columns and every post suggests `ANY()` and `WHERE().COUNT()>0` or `FirstOrdefault()` won't have any difference.

Can someone help me understand why the 1st query takes around 1 min from code and 2nd one 1 sec from code

Comment: Did you have a look at the executionplan?

Comment: If the same query executes in 1 sec from SSMS but takes over a minute when you run it from code, there must be something else going on, because there is nothing to do after the query. Are you running the first query "cold" and the second query "hot", i.e. before the results expire in the cache? Is anything else accessing the same tables when your one-minute query is running?

Comment: @Peter , I couldnt get the execution plan because of the environment 
 access reasons. But the were anle to pull the sqls.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  it is slow at any time I run it. doesnt matter 1st or 2nd run.  I saw the difference in sql queries created in the back end. one uses select top1 and other uses select count(*) . But since the query runs in almost same time in SSMS di am clue less what is different in LINQ side

Comment: When you ran the "same" query in ssms did you use sp_executesql with the parameter for census_id?

Comment: Did you run SQL Profiler (with appropriate events... batch start/end, etc.) to see the timings and the exact code being run and its duration? This will tell you if the time is really being spent in SQL Server on the query, or in C# code somewhere. It also lets you see the exact SQL being run, and you can then take that and run it in SSMS and look at query plans to find out what the issues are. SQL Profiler is an excellent tool not to be overlooked. And ALWAYS look at query plans in cases like this.

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you running.  The .Linq() syntax was replaced when the external Linq provider was integrated in to NHibernate.  I think in 3.0.  There have been numerous improvements the Linq provider since then.

Answer (score -3):

Is because a count always is speeder than a select with a top.